# VS2010 Load Testing - Restricting ports

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

As per the trouble shooting guide for VS2010 Load Testing (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vststest/thread/df043823-ffcf-46a4-9e47-1c4b8854ca13), I'm trying to restrict the range of ports used for client-controller communication.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\VisualStudio\10.0\EnterpriseTools\QualityTools\ListenPortRange\PortRangeStart
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\VisualStudio\10.0\EnterpriseTools\QualityTools\ListenPortRange\PortRangeEnd

I've set these keys on the client as described but according to netstat the client is still listening on random ports. The controller is attempting to communicate on the same random ports as the client.

Anyone experienced the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone encounters this issue, I've been advised of a solution:

> 1) Close VS
>
> 2) Create my.pkgdef file under
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\my\ with the following content:
>   [$RootKey$\EnterpriseTools\QualityTools\ListenPortRange]
>   "PortRangeStart"=dword:00000400
>   "PortRangeEnd"=dword:00000401
>
> 3) Start VS
>
> 4) Start regedit.exe and check if new
>   values are now under (32 bit registry)
>   HKCU...\10.0_Config\EnterpriseTools\QualityTools\ListenPortRange.
>   If they are not there, close VS,
>   remove the 10.0_Config node and start
>   VS again.
>
> Note that the name of the file and
>   directory does not really matter, what
>   is important that:
>
> A) The file has extension .pkgdef
>
> B) It's under C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions directory (could be in a subdirectory of it).

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vststest/thread/df043823-ffcf-46a4-9e47-1c4b8854ca13